# Implementing signals (Observer pattern): is mutable or const_cast necessary?

Tags: c++, c++11, observer-pattern, signals-slots

I'm implementing my very own `signal`/slot (observer pattern, Qt style) mechanism so I can have a `property` that notifies ... stuff... that is has changed.

I think C++11 provides everything necessary to make a very succint and featureful implementation possible. The "issue" I'm running into is if I want to "connect" to a signal of a `const` object, I need the `signal::connect` function to be const, but modify the list of callbacks/observers. There are two straightforward ways to fix this:

1. `const_cast` the lists inside `connect`.
2. Make the lists `mutable`.

Both seem to me like the same thing (and this has been asked before, *e.g.* in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725375/const-correct-notifier-in-observer-pattern)), and perfectly fine logically, but stylistically questionable. Hence the question. Is there a way around this or is this a truly justified use of `const_cast`/`mutable`?

Some prelimenary code as I have it now:

```
template<typename... ArgTypes>
class signal
{
public:
  template<typename Callable>
  void connect(Callable&& callback) const
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(slots_mutex);
    slots.emplace_back(callback);
  }

  void emit(ArgTypes... arguments) const
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(slots_mutex);
    for(auto&& callback : slots)
    {
      callback(arguments...);
    }
  }

private:
  // mutable here allows to connect to a const object's signals
  mutable std::vector<std::function<void(ArgTypes...)>> slots;
  std::mutex slots_mutex;

};
```

Note I haven't tested this code; this is just a reflection of my current state of mind.

Comment: Non-tested code... tsk tsk...

Comment: @Arnav I'm literally writing the tests now, I just needed to get this design issue out of the way :p.

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand why the `signal` itself should expose `const` methods. Why not let the user of `signal` decide whether they want it to be mutable (or not)?

Comment: @MatthieM. Imagine the signal as a member of an object. If that object is const in a certain context, you cannot simply connect to a signal thereof, which necessitates user code to give up a level of const-correctness. I that's not clear, I can try to provide a code sample of what I mean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`mutable` is usually the better choice for such cases.

Avoid (`const`) casting whenever you can, it's prone for hitting undefined behavior, while `mutable` is guaranteed to be not<sup>1)</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>`mutable` class members are guaranteed not to go to emitted codes `.text` segment for instance.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

> There are two straightforward ways to fix this:
>
> 1. `const_cast` the lists inside `connect`.
> 2. Make the lists `mutable`.

In fact there is a third choice (which is a general purpose would-be workaround, had C++ not provided the `mutable` keyword) - you can move the concerned data out of the syntactical object:

```
class X
{
    mutable int           i1_;

    // Data pointed to by i2_ semantically belongs to this object
    // but doesn't constitute a syntactical part of it so it is not
    // subject to const-correctness checks by the compiler.
    std::unique_ptr<int>  i2_;

public:
    void constFunc() const {
        i1_  = 123;
        *i2_ = 456;
    }
};
```

Despite the availability of this additional option, I still concur with [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%cf%80%ce%ac%ce%bd%cf%84%ce%b1-%e1%bf%a5%ce%b5%e1%bf%96)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39182556/6394138) that the `mutable` keyword is the right choice for such cases. It explicitly documents in a standardized way (e.g. allows to be grepped) that the conceptually `const` operations of this class may not be technically non-mutating. This is good to know, for example, when being concerned with thread safety of `const` functions of the class.

Answer (score 0):

The **signal::connect** does modify **signal::slot**. So, I think the only thing you need to do is change your design. Let **signal::connect** be mutable and callers hold mutable **signal** pointers.